# Vue Vuetify Performance/Freeze Issue

Tags: javascript, performance, vuejs2, vuetify.js

I'm building an vue2.js app, which gets data from an API and shows it within an vuetify [data-iterator](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/data-iterators/) and on a [leaflet map](https://vue2-leaflet.netlify.app/).

The `App.vue` component handles the communication between the other components (FilterPanel, ListPanel and MapPanel) ...

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <v-app id="inspire">
      <v-app>
        <v-navigation-drawer app width="26em" class="pb-16 pb-lg-0">
          <FilterPanel @change="getData" />
        </v-navigation-drawer>
        <v-sheet id="widget-panel" app class="open" :elevation="8">
          <v-container
            class="grey lighten-5 scrollContainer"
            style="display: flex; overflow-y: auto; flex: 1"
          >
            <ListPanel :loading="loading" :data="data">
              <template #card="{ data }">
                <DataCard :data="data" :id="'data' + data.id"></DataCard>
              </template>
            </ListPanel>
          </v-container>
        </v-sheet>
        <v-main>
          <MapPanel :loading="loading" :data="data" />
        </v-main>
      </v-app>
    </v-app>
  </div>
</template>
```

.. and the the API call to get the data.

```
...
  methods: {
    getData() {
      this.loading = true;
      fetch("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts")
        .then((response) => response.json())
        .then((json) => (this.data = json))
        .finally(() => (this.loading = false));
    },
  },
...
```

Within the `ListPanel.vue` component an slot is defined, so it can be used somewhere else with other data visualization.

```
<template>
  <v-data-iterator
    no-results-text="no - data"
    loading="loading"
    loading-text="loading - data"
    no-data-text="no - data"
    :items="data"
    hide-default-footer
    disable-pagination
  >
    <template v-slot:default="props">
      <v-row>
        <v-col v-for="item in props.items" :key="item.id" cols="12">
         <slot name="card" :data="item">
            no slot provided
          </slot>
        </v-col>
      </v-row>
    </template>
  </v-data-iterator>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "ListPanel",
  props: ["data", "loading"],
};
</script>
```

The `MapPanel.vue` component shows all data entries on the map with clickable markers, which will open popups to show some information about the data. The map also holds an loading indicator (`v-progress-linear`) to show if data is loading or not.

```
<template>
  <l-map
    id="map"
    ref="myMap"
    :style="styleObject"
    v-if="showMap"
    :zoom="zoom"
    :center="center"
    :options="mapOptions"
  >
    <v-progress-linear
      style="z-index: 800 !important"
      :indeterminate="loading"
      :active="loading"
      absolute
      top
      color="info"
    ></v-progress-linear>
    <l-tile-layer :url="url" :attribution="attribution" />
    <l-control-zoom position="bottomright"></l-control-zoom>

    <l-marker
      v-for="(item, index) in markers"
      :key="'marker-' + index"
      :lat-lng="item.location"
    >
      <l-popup :options="getPopupOptions(item.id)">
        <DataCard :data="item" showRequest flat></DataCard>
      </l-popup>
    </l-marker>
  </l-map>
</template>
```

For better visual representation I'm using an reusable component (DataCard) with [v-card](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/cards/) to show the necessary data.

I have setup a simplified version of the app. https://codesandbox.io/s/sleepy-hoover-s5w5l

**Loading the app or getting the data, let the app freezes for some seconds. You'll see it at the progress bar on the top. The animation stops!**

I figured out, that the v-card component is slowing down the whole app. If I remove the card component entirely, loading the data seems to work just fine.

Getting the data from the API isn't the problem, since getting the data from it is very fast.

Vue DevTools Extension within FireFox shows Problems with the Map Markes and the DataCard component.

So I'm asking, what I'm doing wrong with the [DataCard Component](https://codesandbox.io/s/sleepy-hoover-s5w5l?file=/src/components/DataCard.vue) ?

Comment: Please add relevant code to the question. If codesanbox.io closes your question will have no value

Comment: Did you even check network tab in dev tools to see maybe whats hanging in there? Also Your sendbox works fine by me... And did you even measure your API response time? What debugging you did? Pretty sure its not Vue's issue.

Comment: The sandbox loads pretty fast for me, less than a second and everything is loaded. The list is quite large, it loads 100 DataCard components in the sandbox, and there are a lot of dynamic content being rendered. Maybe implement pagination to not load so much.